# Starting out with Python Falling Distance

Tags: python

For this problem I'm suppose to be getting meters back from the falling_distance function. I cant seem to get the produced calculations of variable d. It just gives me these letters and numbers I've never seen before here is my code:

```
gravity = 9.8
def falling_distance(fall):
    d = (1/2) * gravity * (fall**2)
    return distance
def main():
  print('Seconds\tDistance')
  print('------------------')
  for sec in range(1, 11):
     print(sec,'\t', falling_distance)
main()
```

Output:

```
Seconds Distance
------------------
1    <function falling_distance at 0x7f04ab566c80>
2    <function falling_distance at 0x7f04ab566c80>
3    <function falling_distance at 0x7f04ab566c80>
```

Comment: Can you please add the output you are currently getting

Answer (score 4):

You never called the function -- instead, you printed the *function* value, which is a Python object reference.

```
for sec in range(1, 11):
    print(sec,'\t', falling_distance(sec))
```

You also have to return the value you computed -- use either `d` or `distance`.  With those two changes, your program works nicely:

```
Seconds Distance
------------------
1    4.9
2    19.6
3    44.1
4    78.4
5    122.50000000000001
6    176.4
7    240.10000000000002
8    313.6
9    396.90000000000003
10   490.00000000000006
```

Comment: Thanks man really thankful for help. I had another question I've been wondering about. What is the purpose of []? This is a empty list right? What is it used for?

Comment: @Janes  (1) A separate question belongs in a separate posting; (2) This is a basic tutorial question; you're on the wrong site.  Use your browser search for "Python empty list".